# Necessary and sufficient condition of injectivity for a module based on exact sequences

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra

> Show that Q is injective if and only if, whenever $$0\to A\stackrel{f}{\to} B\stackrel{g}{\to} C\to 0$$ is exact, then $$0\to \mathrm{Hom}_R(C,Q)\stackrel{g^*}{\to} \mathrm{Hom}_R(B,Q)\stackrel{f^*}{\to} \mathrm{Hom}_R(A,Q)\to 0$$ is exact.

I have no idea how to start on this problem. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: $\mathrm{Hom}_R(-,Q)$ is always left exact, so this question is really about whether $Q$ is injective if and only if $f^*$ is onto. Think about what that means and how it relates to the definition of injective module.

Comment: What is your definition of "injective"?  This property is often taken as the definition itself.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1168498/equivalence-of-definitions-of-injective-modules

Comment: Or alternatively https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1155248/characterization-of-projective-and-injective-modules

Comment: I have taken the liberty to modify your title "Let Q be an R-injective R-module" which wasn't a title into a true one. Next time, pay attention to it.

Comment: @JeanMarie Thanks for the clearer title.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I think I understand this reduction of the problem. But I don't see how to proceed from there.

Comment: I had made a copy paste error on the new title. I just fixed it.

Comment: @davidh: $f^*$ being surjective is about how given a function from $A$ to $Q$, you need a function from $B$ to $Q$ that satisfies `some condition`. Being injective, **by definition** is about how certain functions from $A$ to $Q$ will give `some functions with some condition`. Gee... I wonder if the two are related?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I see. Thanks a bunch.