# Equivalent Definition of injective $R$-module using exact sequences

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, homological-algebra, exact-sequence, injective-module

We call an $R$-module $D$ injective if one of the two equivalent conditions holds:

1. If $0 \rightarrow A \rightarrow B \rightarrow C \rightarrow 0$ is an exact sequence of $R$-modules then the induced sequence $0 \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}(C,D) \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom} (B,D) \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom} (A,D) \rightarrow 0$ is also exact.
2. Every short exact sequence $0 \rightarrow D \rightarrow Y \rightarrow X \rightarrow 0$ of $R$-modules splits.

I was able to prove 1. $\implies$ 2. but unable to prove the other direction. I don't know what short exact sequence $0 \rightarrow D \rightarrow Y \rightarrow X \rightarrow 0$ I should consider for the converse direction. If possible a answer that is not using Category theory would be helpful.

Comment: The fact that the other implication is not obvious is because in many categories it is not true. You need to use the fact that the category of $R$ modules has enough injectives. If you see the analogous proof for projective modules you use the fact that every projective module is direct sum of a free module. You will need to use something similar here

Comment: @Math_Images_Only I suppose if I can show that for each $R$-module $D$ we can find an $R$-module $M$ such that $D$ is a submodule of $M$ then we have a short exact sequence $0 \rightarrow D \rightarrow M \rightarrow M/D \rightarrow 0$ which by assumption of (2) splits, so $M \cong D \oplus M/D$. It should be possible to show that if $M$ is injective so must it's summands, so $D$ must be injective. But how do I show that first part?

Comment: check the question linked by Ruy. I think your question is a duplicate

Comment: @SirSocket Regarding your last question, it is not trivial that each module embeds in an injective module. You can check one proof [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1168498/equivalence-of-definitions-of-injective-modules). I think @Ruy’s answer is much more elementary (you only need to know some basic properties of the pushout).